# Unity 3d error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ParticleEmitter' could not be found

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

> "Assets\ParticleScaler\ParticleScaler.cs(99,12): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ParticleEmitter' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

I was looking everywhere for the issue. I found some answers in stackoverflow, some similar errors, I did everything they say but they don't work ..
Any time I try an answer get the same error with the name of what I defined again.
I have been looking for the answers for few days and no answer for this..
I will be so thankful if you help me to solve this issue.
thanks

This script will only work in editor mode. You cannot adjust the scale dynamically in-game!

```
    using UnityEngine;
    using System.Collections;
    using UnityEngine.ParticlesLegacyModule; // i defined particleEmitter here!

    #if UNITY_EDITOR 
    using UnityEditor;
    #endif

    [ExecuteInEditMode]
    public class ParticleScaler : MonoBehaviour 
    {
        public float particleScale = 1.0f;
        public bool alsoScaleGameobject = true;

        float prevScale;

        void Start()
        {
            prevScale = particleScale;
        }

        void Update () 
        {
    #if UNITY_EDITOR 
            //check if we need to update
            if (prevScale != particleScale && particleScale > 0)
            {
                if (alsoScaleGameobject)
                    transform.localScale = new Vector3(particleScale, particleScale, particleScale);

                float scaleFactor = particleScale / prevScale;

                //scale legacy particle systems
                ScaleLegacySystems(scaleFactor);

                //scale shuriken particle systems
                ScaleShurikenSystems(scaleFactor);

                //scale trail renders
                ScaleTrailRenderers(scaleFactor);

                prevScale = particleScale;
            }
    #endif
        }

        void ScaleShurikenSystems(float scaleFactor)
        {
    #if UNITY_EDITOR 
            //get all shuriken systems we need to do scaling on
            ParticleSystem[] systems = GetComponentsInChildren<ParticleSystem>();

            foreach (ParticleSystem system in systems)
            {
                system.startSpeed *= scaleFactor;
                system.startSize *= scaleFactor;
                system.gravityModifier *= scaleFactor;

                //some variables cannot be accessed through regular script, we will acces them through a serialized object
                SerializedObject so = new SerializedObject(system);

                //unity 4.0 and onwards will already do this one for us
    #if UNITY_3_5 
                so.FindProperty("ShapeModule.radius").floatValue *= scaleFactor;
                so.FindProperty("ShapeModule.boxX").floatValue *= scaleFactor;
                so.FindProperty("ShapeModule.boxY").floatValue *= scaleFactor;
                so.FindProperty("ShapeModule.boxZ").floatValue *= scaleFactor;
    #endif

                so.FindProperty("VelocityModule.x.scalar").floatValue *= scaleFactor;
                so.FindProperty("VelocityModule.y.scalar").floatValue *= scaleFactor;
                so.FindProperty("VelocityModule.z.scalar").floatValue *= scaleFactor;
                so.FindProperty("ClampVelocityModule.magnitude.scalar").floatValue *= scaleFactor;
                so.FindProperty("ClampVelocityModule.x.scalar").floatValue *= scaleFactor;
                so.FindProperty("ClampVelocityModule.y.scalar").floatValue *= scaleFactor;
                so.FindProperty("ClampVelocityModule.z.scalar").floatValue *= scaleFactor;
                so.FindProperty("ForceModule.x.scalar").floatValue *= scaleFactor;
                so.FindProperty("ForceModule.y.scalar").floatValue *= scaleFactor;
                so.FindProperty("ForceModule.z.scalar").floatValue *= scaleFactor;
                so.FindProperty("ColorBySpeedModule.range").vector2Value *= scaleFactor;
                so.FindProperty("SizeBySpeedModule.range").vector2Value *= scaleFactor;
                so.FindProperty("RotationBySpeedModule.range").vector2Value *= scaleFactor;

                so.ApplyModifiedProperties();
            }
    #endif
        }

        void ScaleLegacySystems(float scaleFactor)
        {
    #if UNITY_EDITOR 
            //get all emitters we need to do scaling on
            ParticleEmitter[] emitters = GetComponentsInChildren<ParticleEmitter>();

            //get all animators we need to do scaling on
            ParticleAnimator[] animators = GetComponentsInChildren<ParticleAnimator>();

            //apply scaling to emitters
            foreach (ParticleEmitter emitter in emitters)
            {
                emitter.minSize *= scaleFactor;
                emitter.maxSize *= scaleFactor;
                emitter.worldVelocity *= scaleFactor;
                emitter.localVelocity *= scaleFactor;
                emitter.rndVelocity *= scaleFactor;

                //some variables cannot be accessed through regular script, we will acces them through a serialized object
                SerializedObject so = new SerializedObject(emitter);

                so.FindProperty("m_Ellipsoid").vector3Value *= scaleFactor;
                so.FindProperty("tangentVelocity").vector3Value *= scaleFactor;
                so.ApplyModifiedProperties();
            }

            //apply scaling to animators
            foreach (ParticleAnimator animator in animators)
            {
                animator.force *= scaleFactor;
                animator.rndForce *= scaleFactor;
            }
    #endif
        }

        void ScaleTrailRenderers(float scaleFactor)
        {
            //get all animators we need to do scaling on
            TrailRenderer[] trails = GetComponentsInChildren<TrailRenderer>();

            //apply scaling to animators
            foreach (TrailRenderer trail in trails)
            {
                trail.startWidth *= scaleFactor;
                trail.endWidth *= scaleFactor;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: it seems like this "particleScaler" class uses a obsolete component called ParticleEmitter, maybe it doesn't work more in recent versions, try to run this script in a older version and see what happens.

Comment: Another solution that you should try is to check if this "ParticleScaler" class has the UnityEngine namespace defined.

Comment: @Nícolas  i deleted the code file included in paticleEmitter folder from assets, and it sames working now ..but i got new error : NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: what exactly did you deleted? post the code for us to help you

Answer (score 0):

Replace ParticleEmitter by ParticleSystem as ParticleEmitter is obsolete. This worked for me.